# Saving variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on a MATLAB program where I will have a class, here represented as Dummy, and a function which is supposed to create and save a set of Dummy objects, say to the current folder. How can I do this? I thought about creating a matfile containing the constructor arguments for each Dummy object, as done in the code example below. However, save expects a string, so my code doesn't work.

```
classdef Dummy < handle

properties
    foo
end

methods
    function D = Dummy(foo)
        D.foo = foo;
    end
end
end


function generateDummies(n)

for i = 1:n
    Df = matfile(strcat('Df',int2str(i)),'Writable',true);
    Df.foo = i;
    save(Df); %(?)
end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using `matfile`, there is no need to use `save`, it automatically writes when you change something.

Comment: @Daniel Okay, but how do I save the matfile either to the current folder or to a specified folder?

Comment: Pass the path you want to the `matfile` command

Comment: @Daniel I'm afraid I don't know the syntax. Would you please provide it? Should it be something like matfile('folder' 'filename')?

Comment: The first input argument is the complete filename, including folders. You can use relative or absolute path.

Comment: @Daniel Alright, thanks!